# Nginx can't find URL for Flask app provided by socket file

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am trying to access a Flask app using Nginx and Gunicorn. I basically followed the instructions given [here](https://medium.com/faun/deploy-flask-app-with-nginx-using-gunicorn-7fda4f50066a). My Flask app is right now just a simple Hello World called `TPD.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

server = Flask(__name__)
@server.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

I can run this successfully using `python TPD.py`. In the same folder I have a `wsgi.py` file:

```
from TPD import server

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run()
```

Gunicorn can also start the app with no issue using `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:server`. Now I use a systemd unit file called `app.service` that looks like this:

```
[Unit]

# specifies metadata and dependencies

Description=Gunicorn instance to serve Dash app
After=network.target

# tells the init system to only start this after the networking target has been reached

# We will give our regular user account ownership of the process since it owns all of the relevant files

[Service]

# Service specify the user and group under which our process will run.
User=stage

# give group ownership to the www-data group so that Nginx can communicate easily with the Gunicorn processes.

Group=www-data

# We'll then map out the working directory and set the PATH environmental variable so that the init system knows where our the executables for $

WorkingDirectory=/home/stage/sharOnStoNe/plotary/media/notebooks/
Environment="PATH=/home/stage/sharOnStoNe/plotary/media/notebooks/dash_apps/bin"

# We'll then specify the commanded to start the service

ExecStart=/home/stage/sharOnStoNe/plotary/media/notebooks/dash_apps/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:dash_apps.sock -m 007 wsgi:server

# This will tell systemd what to link this service to if we enable it to start at boot. We want this service to start when the regular multi-us$

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Running `sudo systemctl start app` and `sudo systemctl enable app` this creates a `dash_apps.socks` in the correct folder.

Finally in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` I have the following settings:

```
server {
    if ($server_port = 8080) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$http_host:8081/$1;
    }

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    client_max_body_size    200M;
    location /doku/ {
        alias /var/www/html/;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        index index.html;
        autoindex on;
    }
    location /plotary/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
        location /plotary/media/notebooks/ {
                proxy_pass http://10.170.76.24:8888/plotary/media/notebooks/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # websocket headers
        proxy_set_header Updgrade "websocket";
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
    location /plotary/static/ {
        alias /var/www/html/plotary/static/;
                include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                autoindex on;
    }
        location /plotary/media/ {
                alias /var/www/html/plotary/media/;
                include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                autoindex on;
        }
    location /plotary/dash/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/stage/sharOnStoNe/plotary/media/notebooks/dash_apps.sock;
    }
```

Now if I restart nginx using `sudo systemctl restart nginx` all URLs are available except `/plotary/dash/`, where I get a 404 error.

Where did I miss something in these settings?

Comment: I only guess: maybe it should be only `unix:/file/` without `http://` or `http://IP:port` without `unix:`. BUT you should check nginx log files - probably in `/var/log/nginx`

Comment: Hi @furas thanks for your comment! I just left work. I will check the log first thing tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding `:/` to the end of the path to the socket in my nginx configuration. The relevant location block now looks like this:

```
location /plotary/dash/ {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/stage/sharOnStoNe/plotary/media/notebooks/dash_apps.sock:/;
}
```